# Заливка RoR-проекта на хостинг с sqlite

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails

У меня проект сделанный с помощью Ruby on Rails. Будут ли проблемы с заливкой на хостинг если использовать как базу данных - sqlite? Заранее спасибо, за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Это сильно зависит от того, как и куда планируется деплоить приложение. Heroku, например, будет поднимать новый инстанс для запуска кода, и если база будет храниться локально в sqlite, она будет каждый раз удаляться. Можно поднять контейнер, который не будет обнуляться при деплое и линковать базу к нему, но лучше просто с самого начала использовать PostgreSQL или MySQL.